# Ignore a particular field (column) in Realm Android

Tags: android, realm

I have referred [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2288) applied some work around but didn't find the solution for ignoring a particular field during `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(...)` unless and until modified externally.
Any solution or idea will be appreciated

using below dependency

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.2'
    //compile 'com.github.realm:realm-android:v1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.realm:realm-android-adapters:v1.0.0'
```

Comment: 0.87.2 is old. Why not upgrade to 1.0+?

Comment: thanks @Tim tried that but that doesn't helps me from ignoring the field

Comment: Isn't that what the [@Ignore annotation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#ignoring-properties) does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ignore a field when using `copyToRealmOrUpdate`. That is by design. If you want to ignore a field value either do a manual copy or use the JSON methods which will ignore fields if they are missing all together from the JSON, e.g. `createOrUpdateObjectFromJson()`

Comment: ok Sir but the ideas in the link were good and it would be nice if we see that ideas in action in future version of realm

Comment: @Auto-Droidツ if you have a feature request you can propose it here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues